# Node JS - Express - Mongo DB: posting data with extra square brackets in JSON key

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, express

I have tried to post data to node js using express. Below code is I am using for posting data to server.

```
var data = {};
data.opt = [];
data.opt.push({label:"Rahul",name:"Rh"});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/save',
    data: data,
    dataType: "JSON"
});
```

When I am retriving data from NodeJS I am getting like below JSON

```
opt: [ { '[label]': 'Rahul', '[name]': 'Rh' } ]
```

In above data extra square brackets is adding with in key value of the opt

Please help me to how to remove this square box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got this error when I reinstall express 3.x.x. I was using 3.6.0, which had no issue. But 3.18.4 had this problem. I just reverted to 3.6.0 in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works...simply call push....

```
var data = {
    'opt' : [],
};
data.opt.push({"label":"Rahul","name":"Rh"});
```

Comment: Hi Jaleel, Thanks for your help. The code which you given also I tried but its not working...